# Error starting Laravel Homestead after updating to 2.29

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have recently updated my vagrant version to `2.2.9`. When running the command, `vagrant up` I am now getting this error:

```
homestead: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
homestead: Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
homestead: See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I'm not sure what is causing this issue, I've updated the virtualbox, vagrant and the homestead package many times in the past without issue.

My machine is OS Catalina 10.15.5

I have tried uninstalling & re-installing, I've also tried installing an older version of vagrant. Everything results in the same error above. I'm not sure what to do next - any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Thank you, @Aminul!
Here is the output I get:

```
Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Jun 20 19:17:53 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead mysqld[42962]: 2020-06-20 19:17:54 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 20 19:17:54 homestead systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.13 database server.
```

Running: `mysql --version` returns:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

So clearly, it's saying that MariaDB is not started. I can research how to start that. I'm more curious though -- is this something that's happened to homestead? Or is this a result of something else? Normally, I can just `vagrant up` and everything is good to go. I worry that if I mess with things I'm setting myself up for failure down the road.

**EDIT 2**

When running this:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ systemctl start mysqld.service
```

This is what I am prompted with:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'mariadb.service'.
Authenticating as: vagrant,,, (vagrant)
Password:
```

I'm not sure what the credentials are to keep testing.

**ADDITIONAL SOLUTION**

Thank you,Raphy963!
I didn't want to answer my own question, and I was able to find another work-around that hopefully will help someone else.

The application I am working on is not yet in production, so I was able to change my database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

I removed/uninstalled all instances of virtualbox, vagrant & homestead. I also removed the "VirtualBox VMs" directory.

I re-installed everything, starting with VirtualBox, Vagrant & then laravel/homestead. I am now running the latest versions of everything; using the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead) for instructions.

After everything was installed, running `vagrant up` did not create errors, however I was still not able to connect to MySQL.

I updated my `Homestead.yaml` file to the following:

```
---
ip: "10.10.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/<username>/Sites
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:    
    - map: blog.test
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/blog/public

databases:
    - blog
    - homestead


features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false
```

I updated my hosts file to this:

```
10.10.10.10     blog.test
```

Finally, using [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/) I was able to connect with the following:
[image]

My `.env` file in my Laravel application looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I am now able to connect using TablePlus and from my application.

Hope this helps someone!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and spent way too much time trying to fix it. I tried using the new release of Homestead from their GitHub repo (https://github.com/laravel/homestead) which claims to fix this exact issue but it didn't work.

After investigating on my own, I realized the scripts used in Vagrant for homestead to work (This repo over here https://github.com/laravel/settler) has been updated to "10.0.0-beta". I did the following to put it back to "9.5.1".

```
vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 9.5.1
```

Afterwards, I remade my instance by using `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` and MariaDB was up and running once more.

While this might not be the best solution, at least I got it to work which is good enough for me.

Hope it helped!

Comment: I will give this a try! 
I ended up moving my project (not in production) to Postgres which worked, but still was concerning that I completely blew up my local development.

I'll update my post with what I did, then try your solution. Hopefully between the two we can save people the pain! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to investigate what is the cause.

Login to your instance by runing `vagrant ssh` and run `systemctl status mariadb.service` for checking the error log.

Check what is is the error and reply here if you didn't understand.